# Retrofit 2 + RxJava retryWhen

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using Retrofit 2 along with RxJava 2 adapters.

Whenever the server returns 401 Unauthorized, I refresh the token and retry the request:

```
apiCall.retryWhen(es -> es
    .flatMap(e -> {
        if (isUnauthorizedException(e)) {
            return refreshToken();
        }

        return Flowable.<User>error(e);
    }));
```

Where refreshToken is a simple retrofit call:

```
public Flowable<User> refreshToken() {
    return retrofitService.login(userCredentials);
}
```

Now, I would like to limit the number of times such refresh is possible. However, simply adding `take(1)` does not work, because then retryWhen receives onCompleted immediately after onNext and cancels the request before retrying it.

Naturally I could do `take(2)` to achieve the desired effect but it seems like a hack.

What is the most elegant way to achieve it using Rx operators? Also is there an operator with "assertion" logic (to get rid of `if` in the flat map)?

Also I am aware I can achieve the same thing using OkHttp interceptors, but I am interested in Retrofit-RxJava solution.

Comment: Did you try ``retry``? - ``public Flowable<User> refreshToken() {
    return retrofitService.login(userCredentials).retry(3);
}`` - would retry max 3 times before emitting an error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice example from documentation
this retries 3 times, each time incrementing the number of seconds it waits.

```
ObservableSource.create((Observer<? super String> s) -> {

  System.out.println("subscribing");
  s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));

}).retryWhen(attempts -> {

  return attempts.zipWith(ObservableSource.range(1, 3), 
    (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {

    System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
    return ObservableSource.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  });
}).blockingForEach(System.out::println);
```

Output is:

- subscribing
- delay retry by 1 second(s)
- subscribing delay retry by 2 second(s)
- subscribing delay retry by 3 second(s)
- subscribing

you could modify this example according to your requirements.